# Converting a custom data structure into a bean with Spring

Tags: java, spring

We have a custom data structure which needs to be converted into a java bean.
That data structure usually contains everything as a String, but the bean will have typed attributes.

The attributes are named the same in both the data structure and the bean.

The actual target type of the bean is determined at runtime and to spice it up a bit we also need to convert to Joda DateTime objects from custom formatted date strings.

So short of writing a method per possible type, what would be a good solution for this?

Since my code is running in a Spring container, I am currently going for Springs BeanWrapper so I dont have to care about standard conversions (String -> BigDecimal etc.) and configured it with:

- ConversionService + custom Converter
- custom PropertyEditor

However, BeanWrapperImpl has a note saying that it is basically an internal class, so I am a little confused as to how it should be used or if there are alternatives.

Here is the code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;

import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BeanWrapperTest
{
    private static InputDataStructure createInputDataStructure()
    {
        return new InputDataStructure(Arrays.asList(
            map(mapEntry("name", "some name"),
                mapEntry("bigDecimal", "12.34")),
            map(mapEntry("dateTime", "2017-03-02T09:30:00.0Z"))
        ));
    }

    private Map<String, String> toMap(InputDataStructure inputDataStructure)
    {
        return inputDataStructure.data.stream()
            .flatMap(innerMap -> innerMap.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
    }

    @Test
    public void copy_alternative_using_conversion_service()
    {
        // set up a conversion service and add the special date converter
        // and configure BeanWrapper with that conversion service
        DefaultConversionService defaultConversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        defaultConversionService.addConverter(new CustomDateConverter());

        BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(DestinationClass.class);
        beanWrapper.setConversionService(defaultConversionService);

        // copy all values into a Map
        // and loop over that map and use BeanWrapper to copy the properties
        Map<String, String> values = toMap(createInputDataStructure());
        values.forEach(beanWrapper::setPropertyValue);

        // bam!
        System.out.println(beanWrapper.getWrappedInstance());
    }

    @Test
    public void copy_alternative_using_formatters()
    {
        // configure BeanWrapper with a custom property editor
        BeanWrapper beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(DestinationClass.class);
        beanWrapper.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new CustomDateEditor());

        // copy all values into a Map
        // and loop over that map and use BeanWrapper to copy the properties
        Map<String, String> values = toMap(createInputDataStructure());
        values.forEach(beanWrapper::setPropertyValue);

        // bam!
        System.out.println(beanWrapper.getWrappedInstance());
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private static <K, V> Map<K, V> map(Map.Entry<K, V>... entries)
    {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : entries) {
            map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        return map;
    }

    private static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> mapEntry(K key, V value)
    {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(key, value);
    }

    private static class InputDataStructure
    {
        private final List<Map<String, String>> data;

        InputDataStructure(List<Map<String, String>> data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private static class DestinationClass
    {
        private String name;
        private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
        private DateTime dateTime;

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public DestinationClass setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public BigDecimal getBigDecimal()
        {
            return bigDecimal;
        }

        public DestinationClass setBigDecimal(BigDecimal bigDecimal)
        {
            this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
            return this;
        }

        public DateTime getDateTime()
        {
            return dateTime;
        }

        public DestinationClass setDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
            return this;
        }

        @Override public String toString()
        {
            return "DestinationClass{" + "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", bigDecimal=" + bigDecimal +
                ", dateTime=" + dateTime +
                '}';
        }
    }

    private static class CustomDateConverter implements Converter<String, DateTime>
    {
        @Override public DateTime convert(String source)
        {
            // try whatever date format would be expected
            return DateTime.parse(source);
        }
    }

    private class CustomDateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
    {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text)
        {
            // try whatever date format would be expected
            setValue(DateTime.parse(text));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky way to solve your problem. you could convert your object into a json string then using **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper** to write the json strings into your target object